# Prove an inequality (Using Taylor expansion)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials, derivatives, taylor-expansion

> Prove: $\frac{x}{1+x} < \ln(1+x) < x$.

I thought a good practice would be to prove it using Taylor Expansion.

Here's my try:
$$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}...$$

The n=1 Taylor polynomial is:
$$T_1(x) = x$$
and 
$$ ln(1+x) = T_1(x) +  R_1(x)$$

Lets evaluate $R_1(x)$ by Cauchy's remainder formula:

$$R_1(x) = \frac{f^{(2)}(\xi)}{2!}\cdot x^2 = \frac{\frac{-1}{(\xi+1)^2}}{2!}\cdot x^2 = \frac{-x^2}{2(\xi+1)^2} < 0$$

Now, it does prove the right-hand side because $x + R_1(x) < x$ ($R_1(x)$ is negative).
I'm not so sure what should I do for the left-hand side. I'd also like to get general critique for my current work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We apply the mean value theorem on the function $t\mapsto \ln t$ on the interval $[1,1+x]$: there's $\zeta\in(1,1+x)$ such that
$$\ln(1+x)=\frac x\zeta$$
and notice that
$$\frac1{1+x}<\frac1\zeta<1$$

Comment: Very nice, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Using the elementary inequality 
$$
1+x\le e^x
$$
one directly obtains one side of the inequality chain. Replace $x$ by $-y$ and invert to obtain
$$
\frac1{1-y}\ge e^y
$$
and then set $1+x=\frac1{1-y}=1+\frac{y}{1-y}$ or $y=\frac{x}{1+x}$ to obtain
$$
1+x\ge e^{\frac{x}{1+x}}
$$
for the other part of the inequality chain.

Answer (score 1):

Proof:

> Assuming you argued and justified that $ f (x) = Ln (1 + x) $ is
>   continuous and derivable $ \forall x> 0 $.

This is equivalent to writing the interval $ (0, x) $.

By the **Mean Value theorem** $\exists c \in (0,x)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, i.e.
 $\frac{1}{1+c}=\frac{Ln(1+x)-Ln(1)}{x-0}=\frac{Ln(1+x)}{x}$.

We can delimit  $\frac{1}{1+c}=f'(c)$ (*), then:

$\frac{1}{1+x}<f'(c)<1$

But we know that  $f'(c)=\frac{1}{1+c}=\frac{Ln(1+x)}{x}$ (**)

Replacing in (*) we get:

$\frac{1}{1+x}<\frac{Ln(1+x)}{x}<1$

Multiplying the inequality by $x$, we obtain the desired result:

$\frac{x}{1+x}<Ln(1+x)<x$.